# What is the most efficient CUDA Thrust or C++ STL sort predicate to use if I don't need a full, strict ordering?

Tags: c++, stl, cuda, thrust

I have a large array that I must sort in CUDA Thrust or C++ STL. The data is already partitioned into segments by key. My sort must sort the values in certain segments by my predicate while preserving the contiguity of each segment, and the relative order of the segments. What is not needed is for the values in the other segments to be fully sorted. They may be shuffled around within their segment arbitrarily.

I would like to know the most efficient predicate to use for the relative order within certain segments that I don't care about.

```
thrust::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [] (auto a, auto b) {
    return (a.key() != b.key()) ? a.key() < b.key() : // keep segments in place
       (a.needsSorted() ? a.value() < b.value() : (WHAT_GOES_HERE?)); });
```

My predicate for when I care about the values (a.value() < b.value() above) is rather expensive, so I'd like something simpler for when I don't care (the WHAT_GOES_HERE above). Could I use false, for example? This would be inexpensive, but I'm not sure it leads to the sort terminating the soonest.

I'm interested in answers for both GPU and CPU, but mostly GPU.
Thanks.

Comment: `std::sort` requires strict weak ordering so that's out if your comparator doesn't have that.  Is there any reason you can't just find the begin and and end of each segment that needs sorting and just call sort on those segments?

Comment: When you say "that's out" you mean using false is out, right?

Comment: The computational cost of finding each span and calling sort on it may be higher than just calling sort once. On the GPU this will definitely be the case because the overhead of launching a sort kernel on the GPU over the bus is quite high.

Comment: Meaning you can't use `std::sort` if `cmp(a, b) == cmp(b, a)`.

Answer (score 2):

`false` is a valid option, effectively treating all elements with the same segment as equivalent if the segment doesn't need sorting. `true` is not.

Or you can order them by some other method if you want to try. Whether any particular ordering will lead to "the sort terminating the soonest" is likely dependent on the exact implementation and your data, so profiling is really the only way to answer this.

Comment: Seems like using false doesn't satisfy the criterion cited by NathanOliver that you can't use std::sort if cmp(a, b) == cmp(b, a). If the result of cmp() is always false then the two results will be equal. Is this not actually a requirement?

Comment: No, it's not. The actual requirement is that they can't both be `true`.